# When should a C# event run synchronously?

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, events, asynchronous

I had many times that performance problems were caused by C# event-handlers taking longer than expected, effectively blocking the worker-thread while executing.

Since then I always code events to run async (using `BeginInvoke`), without considering first wether it would be strictly necessary or not.

Are there any downside to this approach (besides the minor performance hit)? And in which cases would it be required to run the events on the same thread (except for the obvious case where you want to block while waiting for the result)? There must be some reason why its not the default behaviour.

Comment: Any downsides that apply to asynchronicity would apply to your approach. If in UI context and you change UI in your event handler, you also have a problem.

Comment: Sorry, open-ended questions like this are not recommended for Stack Overflow. Please see the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @SpikeX I think this question fits the bit where it says "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession"

Comment: @SpikeX This is not open-ended. I just ask why async is not the default in .Net?

Comment: Well, in most cases it is really not needed.  BeginInvoke will run the event in the main thread anyway.

Comment: If you always code events to run async without thinking about it you probably have a bunch of race condition bugs that are hard to reproduce because the events run quickly.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "using BeginInvoke". If you don't want to run code on the UI thread, what you need to do is run it in a different thread, not call it with BeginInvoke from the UI thread. You should then use BeginInvoke in that other thread to update the UI back in the main thread. Just calling code within a UI event handler with BeginInvoke will execute the entire code on the UI thread.

Comment: I agree this is an unanswerable question. Or otherwise the answer can only be "NEVER" (i.e. they never _should_). There are cases where events are supposed to run sequentially. FormClosing and FormClosed spring to my mind now. Undoubtedly there are more examples.